How to resize the bar size and adapt the title to the margins in Chapter Veelo style?
I've constructed Chapter with Veelo style in
 \documentclass{report} 

following the instruction contained in this and this answers. However, I set
   \documentclass{report}
   \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

and I have the black bar very close to the title 'Chapter 1' and leaning against the right margin. The wording 'Chapter 1' is also shifted further to the right than the side margins. How could I move the title 'Chapter 1' further to the left and have a black bar that is further away from the title and bigger (a real square, and not a bar leaning against it)?
This is the full code:
  \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
  \usepackage{titlesec} 
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{graphicx}

  \newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}
  \newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
  \newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\HUGE}
  \newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries}

  \newlength\beforechapskip
  \newlength\midchapskip
  \setlength\midchapskip{\paperwidth}
  \addtolength\midchapskip{-\textwidth}
  \addtolength\midchapskip{-\oddsidemargin}
  \addtolength\midchapskip{-1in}
  \setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}


  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
{{\chapnamefont\chaptertitlename}%
\rlap{\hspace{.8em}%
\makebox[\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+1in][s]{{\resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}\hfill%
\rule{46pt}{\beforechapskip}}%
}%
}%
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

 


  \begin{document}

  \pagestyle{empty}

  \chapter{Dummy}
  \lipsum[2]

  \end{document}

Thanks.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

that is not full code, it produces no output so it does not show the problem or allow people to test answers.

what is the intention of declaring and calculating with midchapskip ? You never use that length so you could delete all those lines without changing the output

I edited the original question so that the code produces an output.

@Bml Did you test the code as it is in the question? \usepackage{graphicx} is missing

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No, you're right. I'm adding it editing the original question.

I guess you want “CHAPTER 1” aligned with the right margin and the square next to the page margin.
If you want a square, use the same width and height in \rule.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
  

\newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}% ???
\newcommand*\chapnamefont[1]{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\Huge}
\newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}

\newlength\beforechapskip
\setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
  {%
   \chapnamefont{\chaptertitlename}\enspace
   \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
   \makebox[0pt][l]{%
     \hspace{\dimeval{\paperwidth-\oddsidemargin-1in-\textwidth-\beforechapskip}}%
   \rule{\beforechapskip}{\beforechapskip}}%
  }
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test of chapter title}

\end{document}

I added \bfseries to \chapnamefont because medium weight is too thin compared to the rest of the chapter heading.


Fantastic, +1. I have seen you on GuIT in the past, but have not been able to download your notes on LaTeX. How could I find them?

@Bml I have to find a new web site…

Sorry to bother. How is it possible to slightly increase the space between 'Chapter' and '1'? Thanks.

@Bml Look at the new image and for \enspace in the code.
